# How to know which binary is chosen by npx

Tags: node.js, npx

npx has a series search path , but when a command is chosen to run, I want to know exactly which binary was called.

Is there some thing like `which` command for npx?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out which file NPX runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443090/how-to-find-out-which-file-npx-runs)

Comment: When I ask this question, the which option is not there yet, glad it is implemented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command prints the path

```
npx which <cmd>
```