# How to find out which file NPX runs?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npx

When you run, say, `npx webpack` in a terminal, NPX finds a `webpack` package somewhere and runs it. How to identify the exact location of the binary that NXP runs? I'm looking for a tool like [which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_(command)) in NPX.

Maybe there is an option like this (warning, it's not a real code):

```
$ npx --which webpack
/users/me/my-project/node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

Answer (score 12):

It seems the [which](https://www.npmjs.com/package/which) package has got us covered:

```
$ npx which webpack
/users/me/my-project/node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

Comment: Seems like it works and is more useful than just `which`.